# Is a plugin to a software restricted to the compute capabilities of that software?

Tags: windows, plugins

I'm thinking about developing a plugin for an existing Windows software which provides an API (.NET framework), and way to add a button in their software that starts the plugin. The software runs single-threaded. Now I'm wondering whether my plugin would be restricted by the computing power of the main software, i.e. that my plugin would then also need to run single-threaded or whether I would have access to the entire processing power of the user's PC?